# Hash table in Java with arrays and linear probing

Tags: java, hash-map

I did some manual tests by instantiating the class and it seems to be working okay. I wanted some feedback on the following:

1. Is the code well structured? I notice I have a lot of redundancy. The search and delete methods are almost the same.
2. I use a string to flag deleted keys until they are replaced, is there a better way to do this. Another boolean array maybe?

```
public class HashTable {
    //known limitation: This will break if the key value is set to none because I use none as the identifier string for deleted keys.
        private int capacity;
        String values[];
        String keys[];
        public HashTable(int capacity){
            this.capacity = capacity;
            values = new String[this.capacity];
            keys = new String[this.capacity];
        }

        public int hash(String key){
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<key.length();i++){
                sum+=key.charAt(i);
            }
            return sum%capacity;
        }

        public void add(String key, String value){
            int keyhash;
            int i = 0;
            while(i!=capacity-1){
                keyhash = (hash(key)+i)%capacity;
                System.out.println("Try "+ i);
                if(values[keyhash]==null || values[keyhash].equals("none")) { //add delete flag to this condition after implementing delete.
                    values[keyhash] = value;
                    keys[keyhash] = key;
                    break;
                }

                if(values[keyhash]!=null && keys[keyhash].equals(key)){
                    values[keyhash]=value;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        if(i==capacity-1)
            System.out.println("Table appears to be full,unable to insert value");
        else
            System.out.println("Value inserted successfully.");
        }

        public String get(String key){
            int i = 0;
            int keyhash = (hash(key)+i)%capacity;
            while(values[keyhash]!=null && i<capacity){
                //System.out.println("Try " +i + " of finding the key.");
                if(keys[keyhash].equals(key))
                    return values[keyhash];
                i++;
                keyhash = (hash(key)+i)%capacity;
            }
        return null;
        }

        public void remove(String key){
            int i = 0;
            int keyhash = (hash(key)+i)%capacity;
            while(keys[keyhash]!=null && i<capacity) {
                if (keys[keyhash].equals(key)) {
                    keys[keyhash] = "none";
                    values[keyhash] = "none";
                    return;
                }
                i++;
                keyhash = (hash(key)+i)%capacity;
            }
            System.out.println("Key does not exist in table");
        }


        public void getHashedValues(){
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i<values.length;i++){
                System.out.print(" "+ values[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
```

Comment: If the capacity is a power of 2, then can use bit wise logic instead of modulo which is quite expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I formatted your code and added a `main` method to test the functionality of your `HashTable`.

I removed all System calls from the `HashTable` class and replaced the important text displays with `Exceptions`.  Generally, utility classes don't write to `System.out` or `System.err`.

I modified your `getHashedValues` method to return the values.

I'd change your use of `i` to `index`, but that's a minor point.

All in all, good work.

```
public class HashTableTestbed {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashTableTestbed test = new HashTableTestbed();
        HashTable hashTable = test.new HashTable(3);

        hashTable.add("alpha", "zeta");
        hashTable.add("beta", "theta");
        hashTable.add("gamma", "tau");
        System.out.println(hashTable.get("alpha"));
        System.out.println(hashTable.get("beta"));
        System.out.println(hashTable.get("gamma"));

        hashTable.remove("beta");
        System.out.println(hashTable.get("beta"));

        hashTable.add("beta", "theta");
        System.out.println(hashTable.get("beta"));
    }

    public class HashTable {
        // known limitation: This will break if the key value
        // is set to none because I
        // use none as the identifier string for deleted keys.
        private int capacity;
        String values[];
        String keys[];

        public HashTable(int capacity) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
            values = new String[this.capacity];
            keys = new String[this.capacity];
        }

        public int hash(String key) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
                sum += key.charAt(i);
            }
            return sum % capacity;
        }

        public void add(String key, String value) {
            int keyhash;
            int i = 0;
            while (i != capacity - 1) {
                keyhash = (hash(key) + i) % capacity;
                if (values[keyhash] == null ||
                        values[keyhash].equals("none")) {
                    // add delete flag to this condition
                    // after implementing delete.
                    values[keyhash] = value;
                    keys[keyhash] = key;
                    break;
                }

                if (values[keyhash] != null &&
                        keys[keyhash].equals(key)) {
                    values[keyhash] = value;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (i == capacity - 1) {
                String text = "Table appears to be full, "
                        + "unable to insert value";
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(text);
            }
        }

        public String get(String key) {
            int i = 0;
            int keyhash = (hash(key) + i) % capacity;
            while (values[keyhash] != null && i < capacity) {
                if (keys[keyhash].equals(key))
                    return values[keyhash];
                i++;
                keyhash = (hash(key) + i) % capacity;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void remove(String key) {
            int i = 0;
            int keyhash = (hash(key) + i) % capacity;
            while (keys[keyhash] != null && i < capacity) {
                if (keys[keyhash].equals(key)) {
                    keys[keyhash] = "none";
                    values[keyhash] = "none";
                    return;
                }
                i++;
                keyhash = (hash(key) + i) % capacity;
            }
            String text = "Key does not exist in table";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
        }

        public String[] getHashedValues() {
            return values;
        }

    }

}
```